# How to prepare my data to avoid being unable to infer frequency

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, gluonts

The following code from `pandas/tseries/frequencies.py` is causing my code to fall over:

```
if not self.is_monotonic or not self.index._is_unique:
    return None

delta = self.deltas[0]
ppd = periods_per_day(self._creso)
if delta and _is_multiple(delta, ppd):
    return self._infer_daily_rule()

# Business hourly, maybe. 17: one day / 65: one weekend
if self.hour_deltas in ([1, 17], [1, 65], [1, 17, 65]):
    return "BH"

# Possibly intraday frequency.  Here we use the
# original .asi8 values as the modified values
# will not work around DST transitions.  See #8772
if not self.is_unique_asi8:
    return None
```

The first test, `self.index._is_unique`, passes fine; the second, `not self.is_unique_asi8`, fails, and returns `None`.

I have looked at [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8772) and the corresponding PR but

My code, it its current form, looks like this:

```
db = Database()
df, last_trade_time = db.fetch_trades()

# Convert the time column to a datetime object with the unit of seconds
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')

# Localize the timestamps to UTC
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')

# Ensure uniqueness by adding the index as nanoseconds
df['time'] = df['time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='ns')

# Set DataFrame index
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

dataset = PandasDataset(df, target="price")
```

These `time`s are in seconds, with sub-nanometer precision (from Kraken).

How can I prepare my data? Only a month or so of Python experience here...

I have asked this question in another form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76499857/struggling-to-create-a-unique-datetime-index-in-pandas-dataset)